# I have two action for a single route but not as arming the URL

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem I could not solve, I have a child route, like this:

```
'apps'=>array(
    'type'=>'Segment',
    'options'=>array(
        'route' => '/apps[/[:action[/:id]]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action'  =>  '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults'  =>  array(
            'controller' => 'Apps\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'index'
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'ximages' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/ximages[/[:action[/:id_ximage]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                 ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Apps\Controller\xImages',
                'action' => 'index'
             )
        ),
    ),
```

In the file .phtml I want to access the path `http://miserver/apps/view/1/ximages/images/1` and what I do is the following:

```
echo $this->url(
  'apps/ximages', 
  array(
    'action'=>'view',
    'id' => 1,
    'id_ximage' => 2
  )
);
```

But this code only prints me to the path `http://miserver/apps/view/1/ximages/index/1` and do not know how you can pass the name of the action of the child route.

Answer (score 0):

your route is not properly set, because your params are the same between your main route and your child route (**:action**)

```
'route' => '/apps[/[:action[/:id]]]',

'route' => '/ximages[/[:action[/:id_ximage]]]',
```

the first parameters is defined by what your give here :

```
echo $this->url(
  'apps/ximages', 
  array(
    'action'=>'view',
    'id' => 1,
    'id_ximage' => 2
  )
);
```

so the view parameters is correctly set for your main route, but this params is consumed, and cannot be used again. So in the second params called with the name action you have no params given soi the default is called and for you it's

```
controller' => 'Apps\Controller\xImages',
                'action' => 'index'
```

By the way, your "controller" params is useless ;)

So i advise you to change your child route params :action to anything else, and set the param in your .phtml file like the others.

```
'route' => '/ximages[/[:action2[/:id_ximage]]]',

echo $this->url(
  'apps/ximages', 
  array(
    'action'=>'view',
    'id' => 1,
    'id_ximage' => 2,
    'action2' => 'images'
  )

);
```